# Where is Madame Freona's Tea Kettle in the Tyranny of Dragons (ToD) Adventurers League stories?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, maps

I have this map of Phlan:

[image: Map of Phlan]

It does not list *Madame Freona's Tea Kettle*, however. In *Defiance in Phlan*, it only describes the Tea Kettle as follows:

> Madame Freona’s Tea Kettle (and Freona herself) is a mystery to many.
>   In the tumultuous Phlan, this is a place where people can go to have a
>   drink or meal and escape the tensions of the schemers and the
>   power-hungry. With the Tea Kettle’s reputation as a haven, adventures
>   who can be discreet and behave themselves can often find employment
>   there.

**Is there a designated location for the Tea Kettle, or is it up to the DM to place it somewhere**?

Comment: Yea, I took that more as a sign that it is up to the DM. If it was so much of a mystery then how to the players hear about it (and the many of other adventurers that are at the Tea Kettle). I mean if that is the answer, I will take it, and just place it where ever on the map.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to *DDEX1-14 - Escape From Phlan* (p.11):

> Madame Freona's Tea Kettle is located northeast of Scholar Square--near the bazaar in Podol Plaza.

[Mantor's Library](https://sites.google.com/site/dnd5ewiki/moonsea/phlan/mantors-library) is the largest structure in Scholar's Square, so the Tea Kettle would be one of the buildings between F and D on the map. Also: *Defiance in Phlan* indicated that it contains at least seven tables (p.23) and that there's a stable behind it (p.6)... so the large yellow building between F and D would probably be the best choice.

[image: The yellow building between D and F, circled in red]

Comment: Good point about the information from the missions! I did not think about the stable to help find it. I figured more descriptions of the Tea Kettle would be in the rest of the Adventure League adventures.